Bet sizing problem
Consider the following game: I have a biased coin, which shows Heads with probability $p$ and Tails with probability $1-p$. I then toss the coin. If it comes up Heads, you win $£50$, otherwise you win nothing. If you are only allowed to play this game once, how much would you be willing to pay to play?
I understand that if you had a sufficiently large stack of money yourself, and you were allowed to play this game indefinitely, you'd be happy to pay anything less than $50p$. But I am curious as to whether there is a way you can find a suitable maximum amount you'd be willing to play in this game, or is purely just a personal preference concerning risk neutrality / aversion.
E.g. I guess you could argue you'd still be willing to pay anything less than $50p$, since this is still a +EV call, but is there an objective way in how the variance in this game should alter this betting size?

I would not be willing to bet £24 to play this game, if I only had £24 in the bank account. Obviously, with unlimited trunks of money, you could play it whenever it would have a positive EV, or even negative EV, as long as the game is fun enough. The answer to your question might really depend on the context and the nature of the game.

This is indeed an interesting problem. From an EV standpoint, $50p$ should be the "rational" break point. If you wish to somehow model risk preferences mathematically, you may want to consider using utility functions and relevant theories. For a sequence of wages, the Kelly criterion might be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion#Gambling_Formula

As someone pointed out, it would depend on your utility function, but maximizing the rate of the return of your investments is typically a reasonable assumption to make given no other information- this is what Kelly Criterion does.
$$f = p - \frac{1-p}{B}$$
where $f$ is the fraction of your bankroll to risk, $p$ is the probability of a favorable outcome, and $B$ is the win/loss ratio. It's also worth noting that this equation is specifically for when the loss results in a full loss of your wager.
Suppose that you wager $w$ dollars to play this game, then for what personal wealth (bankroll) would that make sense?
Well let's eliminate some variables with fixed numbers that we know and rearrange the equation:
$$f = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{50}{w}}$$
$$f = \frac{50-w}{100}$$
We know that the wager has to be less than or equal to the fraction of your capital, $C$, that Kelly suggests to be for this bet to make sense.
$$\frac{w}{C} \leq \frac{50-w}{100}$$
$$w \leq \frac{50C}{100+C}$$
